# Tuple element is not getting converted to float during reduceByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am preparing for CCA175, I am using the oldest available version of spark, Spark 1.3.0.

As shown below, I am converting the element to Float while mapping but while reducing it is showing a compile time error.

```
scala> val revenuePerDay = ordersJoinOrderItems.map(x => (x._2._1, (x._1, (x._2._2).toFloat)))
revenuePerDay: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Int, Float))] =
               MapPartitionsRDD[21] at map at <console>:31
```

After mapping I can see that it is mapped as `Float` but when I am running the below command it is showing an error:

```
scala> revenuePerDay.reduceByKey((x,y) => x._2._2 + y._2._2)
<console>:34: error: value _2 is not a member of Float
              revenuePerDay.reduceByKey((x,y) => x._2._2 + y._2._2)
                                                  ^
```

Answer (score 2):

`PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey` works on a pair of *values*:

```
def reduceByKey(func: (V, V) ⇒ V): RDD[(K, V)]
```

Since your tuple is of the form: `(String, (Int, Float))`, the key (`String`) isn't part of the method signature.

`reduceByKey` expects a function of type `(V, V) => V`. Since your input is of type `(Int, Float)`, and result is of type `Float`, this won't work.

Instead, we'll need to use the more verbose `PairRDDFunctions.combineByKey`:

```
revenuePerDay.combineByKey[Float](_._2, (acc, x) => acc + x._2, (x, y) => x + y)
```

Or, you can use the slightly similar `PairRDDFunctions.aggregateByKey`:

```
revenuePerDay.aggregateByKey(0F)((acc, x) => acc + x._2, (x, y) => x + y)
```

#### Edit

Another suggestion by @zero323 is to use `mapValues` with `reduceByKey`:

```
revenuePerDay.mapValues(_._2).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Comment: The second snippet doesn't look right. It is rather a job for combineByKey, don't you think?

Comment: @zero323 Which second snippet? Mine?

Comment: `revenuePerDay.reduceByKey((x, y) => x._2 + y._2)`. At the first glance it shouldn't compile.

Comment: @zero323 Hmm, not sure I follow. He wants to reduce by key and add up the floating points. Why `combineByKey`?

Comment: `(x, y) => x._2 + y._2` is `((Int, Float), (Int, Float)) => Float`, right?

Comment: @zero323 Oh, I see what you mean now. Yup, that won't work. Let me fix my answer.

Comment: Looks better now :)

Comment: @zero323 I think `aggregateByKey` even works better here. What do you think?

Comment: Yup. Also I just noticed that combine by key is not exactly right. Create combiner discards value (`_ => 0F`) but it should take it (`_._2`). To be fair `mapValues(_._2).reduceByKey(_ + _)` could be as efficient in this particular case and more readable.